# How to completely remove and install again PIP on MacOS Sierra (10.x)?

Tags: python, pip, installation

Had PIP working normally until few days ago.
Not sure how.

Trying to run it now and now show issues.
Adding full stack bellow of the error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 487, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install, finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 428, in _check_skip_installed
    req_to_install, upgrade_allowed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 390, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 290, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 194, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 367, in proxy_from_url
    return ProxyManager(proxy_url=url, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 312, in __init__
    proxy = parse_url(proxy_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/url.py", line 189, in parse_url
    raise LocationParseError(url)
LocationParseError: Failed to parse: user:pass
```

Want to try to reinstall pip completely.

What is recommended way to do it?

Comment: You gave us an incomplete traceback. The traceback does indicate this is probably a homebrew installation, so just use `brew install -f python@2`.

Comment: Note however, that Homebrew moved Python 2 to a keg-only version, so if the formula is upgraded, you may have to add a `brew link --force python@2` command to link it back into the default location (this is safe).

Comment: Added full traceback.

Comment: So it fails to parse proxy configuration. What proxy configuration do you have? Check your environment variables.

Comment: Thanks. Just checked Env variable and user/pass for proxy seems fine. I can `curl www.yahoo.com` (or wget from different web sites) without problem. Is there specific proxy that needs to be set for brew/python?

Comment: What does `python2.7 -c 'import urllib; print urllib.getproxies()'` produce?

Comment: Thanks! This command returned bunch of settings and some of them seemed fine but it looks like some were gibberish. It turned out that I start using ZSH recently and when it loads proxy settings (by default) - for some reason it adds non standard characters etc... Will need to fix either proxy settings for ZSH (to prepare them as it likes) or just use regular BASH for now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) (or [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)), run it, and restart your terminal then start using environments.
to create an environment type

```
conda create -n my_project_name python=3.6
conda activate my_project_name
```

Now do all the pip installs and conda installs you want.
Your path is fixed.  Pip is fixed.  Go crazy.

Edit:
Now that you've posted your full traceback it looks like you need to feed the proxy a username and password.  Here is one way to do it.

```
pip install --proxy=https://user@mydomain:port somepackage
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `pip` and Python installations are fine. What's wrong is your proxy configuration.

On OS X, both environment variables and the OS X network configuration can supply proxy information. First find out what configuration you have with:

```
python2.7 -c 'import urllib, pprint; pprint.pprint(urllib.getproxies())'
```

then look for any incorrect configuration in both your network settings (in the system configuration, check active networks for the *proxies* tab), and in your environment variables for `*_proxy` entries (`http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, etc.).

You can manually override proxies by setting one on the command line with the `--proxy` switch:

```
pip --proxy= install ...
```

Note the empty `--proxy=`; or you can set a specific proxy.

If you really did need to re-install your Python setup, you appear to have installed yours with Homebrew, so you can re-install it with `brew install -f python@2`.